# Redirect www to non www and https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking at the simplest and most efficient way of doing the following:

- redirecting www to non www for users and search engines which index
  www.
- redirecting http(s) to http because there was previously an SSL
  certificate which is now being indexed in Google, meanwhile my site
  is actually live on http and the SSL certificate expires in 54 days.

Would there be a way to do both combined in one script?

I am not experienced enough to do this efficiently.

Any help would be a MASSIVE help.

Comment: The https to http redirection won't really help, since the browsers will still stumble when making the initial https request. No way around that.

Comment: @arkascha Well, they would seem to have _54 days_ to get Google and everyone back on HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Typically yo can do both aspects in a single step *if* this is only about one single host name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [END,R=301,QSA]
```

For a more flexible solution, for example if multiple host names need to be recognized, you need to use two separate pairs of conditions and rules.

For old apache http servers you may need to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag. So try this if the above results in an "internal server error" (http status 500).

---

The above apporach works in both, `.htaccess` style files and the real http host configuration. But a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks, I've asked the host to do this I should be able to since my host is not cheap ha.

Do you also have the normal script I can add for simply doing the following:

- redirecting www to non www
- redirecting non www to www

Comment: As said: those three lines will do _both_, redirect https to http _and_ www to non-www. Just use your non-www host name instead of `example.org`.

Comment: Those three lines won't "do both". They won't redirect www to non www for non-HTTPS traffic. (You also don't _need_ the `QSA` flag here.)

Comment: @w3dk Whoops, thanks for pointing out that glitch, I modified the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Read up on [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/):

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>`

Comment: This doesn't redirect _from_ HTTPS (the condition matches HTTP). This also doesn't resolve the www canonicalisation.

Comment: It does, you are incorrect. In regards to www I didn't want to spoon feed.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` - is obviously only successful when HTTPS is "off". This will result in a redirect loop. In regards to www - that is half the question. You've also omitted the `RewriteRule` flags, so this will result in an implied 302 (temporary) redirect and processing will continue to any directives that follow. And you shouldn't include the `<IfModule>` wrapper here either - unless this is expected to work successfully with mod_rewrite disabled.

Comment: I should of previously stated it was tried and tested successfully to save you the explanation of why you think it won't work. My bad.